# Why does Redux store show my state, but react component says its undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm building an app with react-redux and am having issues with my redux store. I can see from Redux devTools that when i click on an element inside `RenderPlayerTransferList` the action creator is called correctly and the store updates. However, the react component itself returns undefined when trying to access `this.props.currentSquad` (the state object updated by the action creator which i then mapped to props). Does anyone have any idea why this is? (Note i am using redux thunk)

Relevant code:

Relvent code from main react component:

```
handleTransferPlayerClick=(playerId)=>{

            if (this.props.selectedPlayerFromTeamSheet){
                this.props.addPlayerToSquad(playerId)


                //add new squad into playerIconProps

                this.playerIconProps.playerNames[this.props.selectedPlayerFromTeamSheet.iconKey] = this.props.players[this.props.currentSquad.newAdditions]
                console.log(this.playerIconProps)

            }
        }

const mapStateToProps=(state)=>{
    return {players:Object.values(state.playerDatabase),
            selectedPlayerFromTFLId:state.transfers.TFLPlayerId,
            selectedPlayerFromTeamSheet:state.transfers.selectedPlayer,
            currentSquad: state.squad
    }

}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getPlayers, selectPlayerFromTFL, selectPlayerFromTeamSheet, addPlayerToSquad})(Transfers)
```

action creator

```
export const addPlayerToSquad = (playerId)=>{

    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        const state = getState().transfers


        const payload = {currentSquadMemberId: state.selectedPlayer.iconKey, newSquadAdditionId: playerId}

        //recives object with playerId and Iconid t
        dispatch({type:ADD_PLAYER_TO_SQUAD, payload:payload})
    }
}
```

Reducers

```
const squadDatabase = {currentSquad: {
    0: null,
    1: null,
    2:null,
    3:null,
    4:null,
    5:null,
    6:null,
    7:null,
    8:null,
    9:null,
    10:null,
    11:null,
    12:null,
    13:null,
    14:null,
    15:null
    }, newAdditions: null}

export default (state=squadDatabase, action)=>{

    switch(action.type){
        case ADD_PLAYER_TO_SQUAD:
            return {...state, currentSquad: {...state['currentSquad'], [action.payload.currentSquadMemberId]:action.payload.newSquadAdditionId}, newAdditions: action.payload.newSquadAdditionId}
        default:
            return squadDatabase
    }
}
```

reducers combined here...

```
export default combineReducers ({
    // set state object to auth
    auth: authReducer,
    form: formReducer,
    playerDatabase: playerDatabaseReducer,
    transfers: transfersReducer,
    squad: squadReducer
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without running it, it looks like you might need to change

```
return squadDatabase
```

to

```
return state
```

Otherwise it looks like that value will always be hard-coded?

And in `mapStateToProps`, change

```
currentSquad: state.squad
```

to

```
currentSquad: state.squad.currentSquad
```